# Single letter answer options for quiz

Tags: translation

I have a trivia game that I'm translating into japanese.

I usually use single letter answer options like:

```
A. John
B. Ashley
C. Peter
```

Would I have to present it differently for the Japanese audience?

Comment: Unless you're translating for kindergartners, you can safely use `A., B., C...`.